# Sequence of rules

Tags: input, yii, controller, yii-validation

My application is not working correctly with my input parametres.

I have 2 rules at config urlManager:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<factor:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<factor:\w+>/<ids:((id\d+)|\d)+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
```

At my action I try 2 inputs: `id12id78` and `87`(any number).

With the first input, the action gets `id12id78`, but if I try the second input, my `$ids` parameter is empty.

How I can fix the bug?

Answer (score 0):

Well, nothing strange :

- `id12id78` : the second rule will be applied : `$ids => id12id78`
- `87` : the **first** rule will be applied : `$id => 87`

I don't think you need to different params here, you should use only `id`, e.g. :

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<factor:\w+>/id<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',   
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<factor:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```